# How to pass single check box value from a table containing 5 rows using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs

I want to bind only one checkbox value from a table containing 5 rows. I'm displaying the table using ng-repeat from database

```
<table>
    <tr data-ng-repeat="serviceTable in dataTable ">  
        <td> {{ serviceTable.serviceId }} </td>
        <td> {{ serviceTable.serviceName }} </td>
        <td> {{ serviceTable. amount }} </td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="service.serviceId"></td>
    </tr> 
</table>
```

I want to pass only one integer value(service Id's like 1, 2,3) in ng-model after selecting the checkbox and its value should be passed to the ng-model.

Comment: What do you mean by `one checkbox value from a table containing 5 rows` ? 5 rows contain 5 checkboxs, what you want if i click 1st and 3rd checkbox ?

Comment: @Reza Yes 5 rows contain 5 checkboxes but it should allow to select only one checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to achieve `group radio button` behaviour from `checkbox`

In your checkbox add a model that will store specific checkbox status and a onchange listener. Inside listener make them all unchecked except current.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-change="onChange($index)" ng-model="checkboxStatus[$index]">
```

In controller

```
$scope.checkboxStatus = {};
var previousCheckedIndex = null;
$scope.onChange = function (idx) {
    if (previousCheckedIndex > -1 && previousCheckedIndex !== idx)
        $scope.checkboxStatus[previousCheckedIndex] = false;
    previousCheckedIndex = idx;
};
```

Using loop:

```
$scope.checkboxStatus = {};
$scope.onChange = function (idx) {
    for (var key in $scope.checkboxStatus) {
        if(key != idx) $scope.checkboxStatus[key] = false;
    }
};
```